Flutter Web - Go over a button which has not the focus
I'm exploring flutter on a small project, and in this project I have a stack where I have a form and a button to go back on the previous page.
But each time the focus is on an input and I go over the "go back" button, I have the following error
errors.dart:296 Uncaught Error
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:296:3)
    at Object.assertFailed (errors.dart:29:3)
    at Object._computeOffsetForInputs (event_position_helper.dart:64:37)
    at Object.computeEventOffsetToTarget (event_position_helper.dart:32:14)
    at [_convertEventsToPointerData] (pointer_binding.dart:1037:30)
    at pointer_binding.dart:976:9
    at pointer_binding.dart:930:7
    at loggedHandler (pointer_binding.dart:531:9)
    at Object._checkAndCall (operations.dart:426:37)
    at Object.dcall (operations.dart:431:39)
    at ret (js_allow_interop_patch.dart:17:11)

If the focus is not on the input, it works well.
Do you have any idea how to fix it ?

Context :
• Flutter version 3.22.0
• Dart version 3.4.0
• DevTools version 2.34.3
Main widget
class ResetPasswordView extends StatelessWidget {

  const ResetPasswordView({
    super.key,
  });

  Widget formSection(BuildContext context, ResetPasswordViewModel viewModel) {
    final AppLocalizations l10n = AppLocalizations.of(context);
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      // TODO Max : A bouger dans le layout
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          AppSpacer.p64(),
          // TODO Replace by image
          if (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 650)
            const Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 100),
          AppSpacer.p8(),
          Form(
            key: viewModel.formKey,
            child: FocusScope(
              node: viewModel.focusScopeNode,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  InputEmail(
                    controller: viewModel.emailController,
                    autofocus: true,
                    enabled: !viewModel.isBusy,
                    onChange: viewModel.onFormChange,
                    onEditingComplete: () async => viewModel.onEditingCompleted(
                        context: context, submit: true),
                  ),
                  if (viewModel.busy(viewModel.isResetPasswordButtonEnabled))
                    const CircularProgressIndicator()
                  else
                    SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 8.0),
                        child: FilledButton(
                          onPressed: viewModel.isResetPasswordButtonEnabled
                              ? () async => viewModel.resetPassword(context)
                              : null,
                          child: Text(
                            l10n.reset_password_view_reset_password,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AppLocalizations l10n = AppLocalizations.of(context);
    final GoRouter router = GoRouter.of(context);
    return ViewModelBuilder<ResetPasswordViewModel>.reactive(
      viewModelBuilder: () => ResetPasswordViewModel(router, l10n),
      builder: (context, viewModel, _) => AppScaffold(
        body: AuthenticationLayout(
          widget: formSection(context, viewModel),
          isBackArrow: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticationLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget widget;
  final bool isBackArrow;

  const AuthenticationLayout({
    required this.widget,
    this.isBackArrow = false,
    super.key,
  });

  Widget rightForm(Widget widget, double screenHeight, double width) {
    return new Container(
      width: width,
      height: screenHeight,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromRGBO(12, 71, 28, 1)),
      // TODO Max : A changer et à sortir dans le thème
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 64),
        child: widget,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MediaQueryData m = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return Stack(
      children: [
        rightForm(widget, m.size.height, m.size.width),
        if (isBackArrow)
          InkWell(
              onHover: (value) {
                print(value);
              },
              onTap: () => GoRouter.of(context).pop(),
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_rounded))
      ],
    );
  }
}


I want to be able to use the "go back" button without issues
